# React Authenication

Tags: reactjs, authentication

i am doing an authithication in my web.I have done the login page and logout link and want my navbar change depending on my loginstatus,so i choose to use the localstorage.The loginstatus dont change after i login in the localstorage .can anyone know whats going on with my code?Through the console, the problem should be occur on the login page happened together with the logout(form the console).But i cant figure out the reason on it.Or is there any better approach on handling the authication?
Here are part of  my code in index.js:

```
function handlelogout() {
  //setLoginStatus(false);
  console.log("logged out");
  //localStorage.removeItem('loginstatus')
  localStorage.setItem('loginstatus',false)
 
}  



console.log("username:" +username)   
const login=()=>{//console.log("loginstatus"+loginStatus)
  //setLoginStatus(true);
  //localStorage.removeItem('loginstatus')
  localStorage.setItem('loginstatus',true);
  console.log("login");} 
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Layout  /* loginstatus={loginStatus}  */// <-- boolean true/false
  logout={handlelogout}/*  search={(searchvalue)=>handlesearch({searchvalue})} */ />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/:id" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login   login={login } handleusername={(name)=>{username=name;console.log("username: "+username)}} />}/>
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register login={login } handleusername={(name)=>{username=name;console.log("username: "+username)}}/>}/>
      <Route path="/info" element={<Info username={username} />}/>
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

logout link in navbar(layout.js)

```
var loginStatus=localStorage.getItem('loginstatus')
{loginStatus ==='true' ?
             <><form onSubmit={props.logout()}><Nav.Link style={{ 'color': "white" }} href='/' type='submit'>Logout</Nav.Link></form>{/* <Nav.Link onClick={handlelogout} style={{ 'color': "white" }} href='/' type='submit'>Logout</Nav.Link> */}<NavDropdown style={{ 'color': "white" }} title="Your account" id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action3">Stored News</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action4">
```

loginpage(login.js):

```
if(passwordRef.current.value===res.data){
        console.log("Ture Password")
        props.handleusername(nameRef.current.value)
        props.login();
        navigate('/');
```

console:

```
a123456
login.jsx:67 Ture Password
index.js:47 username: alex
index.js:36 login
layout.jsx:28 layout: true
index.js:23 logged out
layout.jsx:28 layout: false
```

Comment: Do you want to handle the login/logout state with only Localstorage?

Comment: Yes,May i know do this work?

Comment: check answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({ userName: "", password: "" });
  const [userStatus, setUserStatus] = useState(false);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("loginstatus", "1");
    setUserStatus(true);
  };

  const handleLogout = () =>{
    localStorage.removeItem("loginstatus")
    setUserStatus(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const isUserLogined = localStorage.getItem("loginstatus");
    setUserStatus(Boolean(isUserLogined));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <nav>
          {userStatus ? (
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <input
                placeholder="password"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setUserInfo((prev) => ({
                    password: e.target.value,
                    userName: prev.userName,
                  }))
                }
              />
              <input
                placeholder="username"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setUserInfo((prev) => ({
                    userName: e.target.value,
                    password: prev.password,
                  }))
                }
              />
              <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```